# Good H323 Proxy server

Tags: video, video-conferencing, h.323

Is there any open source good h323 proxy server to be used for video conferencing?

```
In C or C# ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [GNU Gatekeeper](http://www.gnugk.org/). Its writtten in C++ and can be configured to be a H.323 proxy.